# Error trying to connect to a droplet in analogsea

Tags: r, digital-ocean, plumber

The initial attempt was to use analogsea to create a droplet using do_provision, but it seems that the problem is that I just can't seem to get ssh working. I'm not sure if something is wrong with my DO account or something is wrong with my computer, but it definitely seems like everything in the manuals indicates it will be easy, and it just isn't working no matter what I try. I keep getting the error:

```
Error: Authentication with ssh server failed
```

Now, I've tried multiple keys, I've tried using all keys on my account. I've tried deleting down to one key and using that. I even tried on another computer. So I'm just not sure what else to try, and given the nature of the problem, I'm not sure how to give you something reproducible either.

```
library(analogsea)
library(plumber)

Sys.setenv(DO_PAT = myauthentication)

mydrop <- do_provision(name = "MyTestDroplet", region = "nyc3")
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I didn't know as primarily an R programmer and not a web developer was that the analogsea package requires that you have all of your keys in the ~/.ssh folder (which, on Windows, R likes to make your My Documents folder your ~, which doesn't quite make sense to me since it's more analogous to c:\Users\username, but anyway... You need to set up your ssh keys and put them in .ssh. However, I don't really recommend using the plumber setup for your DO server, because it doesn't really work very well, it won't get you where you want to go, and ultimately, you're going to just be confused. So instead, you should really consider using the analogsea package and follow some of the relatively good (albeit somewhat confusing) advice elsewhere.